# select text in to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an Android application. In my app I am facing a strange problem.Please have a look on my screen.[image]

when i select any thing from selction box then it will add twice to the edittext.

the following is my code for edittext

```
snd_txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onTextChanged"+start+"b4"+before+"count"+count);
            if (start>0) {

                    int m=snd_txt.getText().toString().lastIndexOf(".");
                    makeColorText(m,snd_txt.getText().toString().length());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });




public void makeColorText(int num,int last) {

    int start=last-44;
    if (start<1){
        start=0;
    }
     SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(snd_txt.getText());

     ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.Gray_Light), 0, start,0);
     ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), start, last, 0); 
    // customize ss here
    // ...



    snd_txt.setText(ss);
    snd_txt.setSelection(last);
}
```

If i comment the `snd_txt.setText(ss);` statement .the the edittext will work perfectly. But I can't do that.I used that method to change edittext color at runtime. working fine for all the time..But at the time of selecting predictions will add the word two times.

Anybody have any idea to solve, Please help me.

Edit:  How can I create a custom edittext with multicolor text.. for eg: current line in blue and previous are black.something like that

Comment: share some code and explain your problem with a bit more details.

Comment: what is your problem. i don't get u

Comment: @AkashSingh...Pls have a look on my screenshot..selecting any word will add two times in edittext..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by changing my code.

```
snd_txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (start>0) {
                 int m=snd_txt.getText().toString().lastIndexOf(".");
         makeColorText(snd_txt.getText().toString().length(),count);    
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

public void makeColorText(int last,int count) {

    int start=last-44;
    if (start<1){
        start=0;
    }

    String s=snd_txt.getText().toString();

    if (count==before_val&count!=1) {

        s=s.substring(0, last-before_val);
        last=last-before_val;
    }

     SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);

     ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.Gray_Light), 0, start,0);
     ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), start, last, 0); 
    // customize ss here
    // ...



         snd_txt.setText(ss);


     before_val=count;


    snd_txt.setSelection(last);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a think which can `causes a Exception due to recycling`. You are watching for text change event of edittext and if there is a text change then you are again setting a text on the EditText so again your text change event will be occurred and you will again set the text so it will continue and it will probably give you Stack overflow exception or hang your UI.

You should use `beforeTextChanged` event and modify the `CharSequence` which you are getting in argument. Probably this will work for you.

Comment: @Dharmendra....its working fine...not making any recursion.. only problem is selecting twice....